# Campaigns per user algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, algorithm

I've got 2 tables named

`marketing_rules` which has a row named `conditions` (JSON Array contatining conditions to validate)
for example: `array('app_version' => '1.0')`

`mobile_users` which containing all the users. it has also the application version that the user use.

my algorithm is working as follows:

- User logs into the application
- Looping all of the Marketing rules that has row `active`=1
- Build query from JSON array (from `conditions` row in `marketing_rules`) - for example: `SELECT * FROM mobile_users WHERE user=USER_ID_LOGGED_IN AND app_version='1.0'`
- If user using this conditions. Outputting the `message` row from `marketing_rules` table to the user.

for some reason my algorithm is getting heavy for the server to handle for multiple users. since it creating alot of DB connections.

What would be the best solution to make this kind of algorithm work more efficient?
I thought about looping ALL of the users daily, and creating them XML's so every time the application needs the message data, it could use it from the XML, instead of creating a query and pulling the message from Database.
But I believe there must be a better solution to my problem.

Comment: Have you considered using NoSQL instead?

Comment: @Khashayar all of the application server is based on MySQL. so it would be alot of work to change it to NoSQL.

Comment: Why don't you take it on the client side? meaning whenever a user logs in it will just check the conditions from marketing_rules and if he applies he send's a meessage himself. This way it will be connection only to marketing table not users which I assume your problem must be the huge amount of users

Comment: You could consider using memcached or redis to cache the result sets for a period of time, or +1 to NoSQL idea.

Comment: @Khashayar Because I want to be able to change the marketing rules from my side. add/remove/edit.. and that the application will only recieve the Message. I will read more about NoSQL and consider to use it if thats the only solution.

Comment: @DinRevah since you have Json conditions I suggest looking into couchDB. everything is with json and its really easy to plugin to other libraries. Good luck